# Unexpected behavior in ES6 const assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given the following:

```
const foo = foo; // Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```

Trying to follow up with:

```
const foo = 123; // Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

`foo` is never set, and similar behavior is seen in both Chrome and Firefox.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing here is the temporal dead zone. The variable `foo` has been declared, but not yet initialised. In fact you tried to initialise it as proper, but the evaluation of that expression threw an exception before `foo` could be set to a value. Now it is forever uninitialised - you had only that one chance.

This is a known problem. [From es-discuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/toplevel-let-binding-can-be-left-permanently-uninitialized-after-an-error) (by Jason Orendorff):

> I just realized this has an unfortunate implication for REPLs. Suppose
>   you make this typo:
>
> ```
> js> let x = Math.cso(a)    // oops, TypeError, should be Math.cos
> ```
>
> Now x is irreparably hosed in your REPL. That seems bad.
>
> I guess we can fix this by making the REPL bend the rules of the
>   language. But this is rather hard to do for REPLs implemented in JS.
>   Maybe the rules should just be a little more forgiving.